# Delegates in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I am a newbie to iOS world, so please ignore the obvious.

I am pushing a viewController(HelpViewController) on top of another viewController(MainViewController). When a particular action happens in the HelpViewController, I would like to update a variable inside the MainViewController. I understand for this I need to use delegate.
Here is my delegate header...

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) switchToggled:(BOOL)status;
@end
// Protocol Definition ends here
@interface ViewDelegate : NSObject
{
    // Delegate to respond back
    id <ViewControllerDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) id delegate;

-(void)sendMessage:(BOOL)status; // Instance method

@end
```

and implementation...

```
@implementation ViewDelegate

@synthesize delegate;

-(id)init {

    self = [super init];

    return self;

}

-(void)sendMessage:(BOOL)status
{
    [delegate switchToggled:status];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

So Now If I want to implement Protocol ViewControllerDelegate I need to specify in MainViewController, which I do as follows --

```
MainViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>
```

and

```
#pragma mark - ViewControllerDelegate delegate
-(void)switchToggled:(BOOL)status{
    NSLog(@"Switch Toggled(%d) Message passed to MainViewController",status);
}
```

**My question** is how do I specify Object, which delegate property needs to point to, so that it can come back to MainViewController's "switchToggled".

One way I do is by having property inside HelpViewController as follows -

```
MainViewController.m
HelpViewController *helpVC = [[HelpViewController alloc] init];
helpVC.mainView = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:helpVC animated:YES];
[helpVC release];

HelpViewController.h
    @property (nonatomic) MainViewController *mainView;
HelpViewController.m
@synthesize mainView;
ViewDelegate *myDelegate = [[ViewDelegate alloc] init];
// assign delegate
myDelegate.delegate = mainView;
[myDelegate sendMessage];
[myDelegate release];
```

**Is this correct** way to implement or there is better way to achieve this or am I totally wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see the need for the `ViewDelegate` class; why can't `HelpViewController` call `[MainViewController switchToggled:]` directly? This is the usual pattern so there is no need for an intermediate object.  Unless I've missed something obvious, of course.

Comment: How are you going to use your "ViewDelegate" class? btw it's not suitable name... "Delegate" suffix you should use just in @protocol declaration

Comment: @trojanfoe exactly which is why I dont see any value in doing the way I am doing right now. Also the way I am doing, HelpViewController, still needs to know about MainViewController, which is something I would like to eliminate

Comment: @Injectios I am planning to use this protocol across my classes. Which is why I am creating a seperate class in a seperate header

Comment: @meaning-matters like ur approach and was looking exactly for suggested approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
// HelpViewController.h
@protocol HelpDelegate

- (void)switchToggled:(BOOL)status;

@end


// HelpViewController.m
@interface HelpViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<HelpDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<HelpDelegate>)delegate

@end

@implementation HelpViewController
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<HelpDelegate>)delegate
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.delegate = delegate;
    }
}

- (void)sendMessage:(BOOL)status
{
    [self.delegate switchToggled:status];
}


// MainViewController.h 
#import "HelpViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController.h : UIViewController <HelpDelegate>


// MainViewController.m

- (void)someMethod
{
    HelpViewController* viewController;
    viewController = [HelpViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    ...
}

#pragma mark - Help Delegate

- (void)switchToggled:(BOOL)status
{
    ...
}
```

- Give the delegate a name that makes clear to which class it belongs.
- You don't need the extra class/files for `ViewDelegate`/`ViewControllerDelegate`.  Just define the delegate in header of class it belongs to: `HelpViewController.n` in this case.
- Similar: Implement the delegate method `switchToggled:` in the real class `MainViewController`, and not in the extra/unnecessary class `ViewDelegate`.
- The purpose of delegates is to avoid class dependencies.  By including `MainViewController` in `HelpViewController` you create such a dependency. This is not necessary as I show, and is wrong design.
- You were also creating a circular dependency, because `MainViewController` already needed `HelpViewController` in order to show it, and now they need each other the other way around for sending the event.
- Alternatively you can make `HelpViewController`'s delegate public, have an `init` without argument, and expect users to set it with `helpViewController.delegate = self;` or something.  But this would only make sense when the delegate being set is optional (which don't seems the case here, so adding it to the `init` method is appropriate).

Comment: can't vote up considering my low reputation on stackoverflow, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Request community to vote up the suggested solution. One thing why my delegate is moved out to separate class is to use this protocol globally.

Comment: @katch Indeed to have a global usable delegate, a dedicated header files is the way to go.  And, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tell you what I would have done:

1) the protocol definition is ok, but do NOT create the class ViewDelegate, so:

```
//ViewControllerDelegate.h
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) switchToggled:(BOOL)status;
@end
```

2) Your implementation of the delegate method in MainViewController is ok.

3) Now... the important point:

```
    //interface
@interface HelpViewController : UIViewController //or whatever superclass..
{
    id <ViewControllerDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
//implementation
@implementation HelpViewController

- (void)someMethodWhichCallsTheDelegate
{
    //do something
    ...
    // call delegate
    //if switchToggled: were optional then add the following
    //if ([self.delegate respondToSelector:@selector(switchToggled:)]) {
    [self.delegate switchToggled:status];
}
@end
```

4) Now you have to assign the delegate:

```
//MainViewController.m
HelpViewController *helpVC = [[HelpViewController alloc] init];
helpVC.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:helpVC animated:YES];
[helpVC release];
```

And that's it!

BTW: if this delegate is related only to `HelpViewController`then add the protocol definition where you define the interface of the class, it is not necessary to create a separate header file. If instead the protocol is "global", then it can have some sense to declare it separately.

Comment: yup, the idea was to have this protocol global and use it across other classes in my code.